# Assign exactly one of two resources to a task in project plan

Tags: ms-project, resources

There's a team contributing to my project, call it Team A. Team A is responsible for 200 tasks out of my yearlong, 800-task project. Each of these tasks requires one week to complete.

I don't care who (out of a team of 4 people) performs each task. So, I've created a resource "Team A", with availability 400%, and assigned each of the 200 tasks to the resource "Team A". Now when I level the project plan, MS Project automatically assigns Team A to no more than 4 of these tasks per week.

This has worked great so far, but suddenly one team member, Bob, can only work half-time. So, this team member requires 2 weeks to complete the same task. I don't see how to account for Bob without adding Bob as an individual resource and assigning Bob specific tasks by hand (which would be a pain).

Is there a way to somehow tell MS Project, for each of these 200 tasks, "I have two resources, Team A and Bob. Please assign one of Team A or Bob to this task. Team A takes 1 week to complete the task, and Bob takes 2 weeks"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you now have 350% of the team not 400%.  I would drop the max units to 350% starting when Bob goes part time.  Project will then resource level and spread so there are only a max of 3.5 of the team assigned.

Comment: JulieS--that doesn't work (at least given my current setup) because my tasks are set up to require 1 week for one team member (emphasis on the "one" team member). So, 50% of a team member can't do any work. That said, if I set up tasks to require 2 weeks for 50% of a team member, then I can do as you suggest.  (The only problem is, everyone else's schedule now shows them doing 2 tasks every 2 weeks instead of 1 task every week. But maybe that's OK; for this project, I'm not sure I need to track tasks on a weekly basis.)

Comment: I'm guessing that it takes the 50% resource twice as long because it is the same amount of work as the one week long tasks.  I'd enter the work when assigning - then if a 50% resource is assigned, assuming the task is not fixed duration, the duration should double automatically.

Answer (score 0):

An easy (and perhaps a bit silly) practical solution would be to create 26 one week tasks for every alternate week called "Bob's Other Job" and assign them all to Bob.  Then, MS Project would recognize that Bob is booked on those weeks, and not assign Bob on those weeks.  MS Project would still think that Bob is going to finish your task in 1 week, but you will know that that will actually go into the following week also.

Comment: Amrinder--yeah, that'd do it! (I'm taking your comment to mean that I should keep the availability of the team at 400%, but assign Team A those extra jobs every other week.) Actually, it's not as silly as it sounds; Bob is actually working half-time on my project because he's taken on managerial duties managing the team developing my project! So, I could even call the task "team management". I'd rather not manually schedule a bunch of tasks like this (it's not the most transparent and conceptually accurate), but I'll think about it...

Comment: Great, mvk, glad to see it works.  If so, please accept the answer to mark the question as resolved.